# Lualatex beamer breqn: Text appears four timestimestimestimes, why and how to mitigate?

Tags: beamer, luatex, breqn

In the following example, why does the word Spam appear four times<sub>times<sub>times<sub>times</sub></sub></sub>?

```
$ cat mwe.tex 
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{breqn}
\newcommand{\spam}{\textrm{Spam}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[ \spam \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting PDF converted to PNG]

...and what can I do to get it just once?

I'm using:

- LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238),
- beamer 2015/01/05 3.36,
- breqn 2015/08/11 v0.98d.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which tex version are you using? I tried with TeXLive 206

Comment: @samcarter The problem is caused by compilation with LuaTeX, something around `\mathchoice`.

Comment: @samcarter Added versions for luatex, beamer, breqn.

Comment: Why don't you use \mathrm instead of \textrm?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because of ignorance / old bad habits / bad habits inherited from others / I don't know.  Just now learning from [your helpful answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22353/8141) on the difference.  It appears `\mathrm` does not show the problem that `\textrm` does, so there is the answer to part 2 of my question.

Comment: I have the same versions of TeX Live, LuaTeX, and beamer, but an older version of breqn (v0.98b), which does NOT have this problem.

Comment: Do I need to describe the version of any additional software?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek The `luatex` tag was not yet there when I tried :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is triggered, if the redefinition of `\mathchoice` in package `mathstyle` meets LuaTeX's `\mathstyle`, from package `mathstyle`:

```
\def\mathchoice{%
  \relax\ifcase\mathstyle
    \expandafter\@firstoffour % Display
  \or
    \expandafter\@firstoffour % Cramped display
  \or
    \expandafter\@secondoffour % Text
  \or
    \expandafter\@secondoffour % Cramped text
  \or
    \expandafter\@thirdoffour % Script
  \or
    \expandafter\@thirdoffour % Cramped script
  \else
    \expandafter\@fourthoffour % (Cramped) Scriptscript
  \fi
}
```

`\ifcase` expects a number and continues the expansion until a token is found, which does not contain to a number (non-digit). Thus the first `\expandafter` of case "0" for "display style" is called at the wrong time, when the number is still being read. A `\relax` stops that and should fix the issue:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\def\mathchoice{%
  \relax\ifcase\mathstyle\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoffour % Display
  \or
    \expandafter\@firstoffour % Cramped display
  \or
    \expandafter\@secondoffour % Text
  \or
    \expandafter\@secondoffour % Cramped text
  \or
    \expandafter\@thirdoffour % Script
  \or
    \expandafter\@thirdoffour % Cramped script
  \else
    \expandafter\@fourthoffour % (Cramped) Scriptscript
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\spam}{\textrm{Spam}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering

$\displaystyle \mathchoice{D}{T}{S}{s}$

\[ \spam \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Same answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303324/4427)