# Lualatex compilation problem using cancel and breqn packages

Tags: luatex, breqn, cancel

**foo.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{breqn} % <= this include is causing troubles

\begin{document}

  \[\cancelto{0}{foo}\]

\end{document}
```

compiling produces these results

```
$ lualatex foo.tex
```

[image: lualatex]

```
$ pdflatex foo.tex
```

[image: pdflatex]

I have no clue what is happening, since the log files are clean of any warnings/errors. Does anyone have a clue on this ?

Comment: I think this has come up before, it looks like it is setting all four branches of a `\mathchoice`

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317930/lualatex-beamer-breqn-text-appears-four-timestimestimestimes-why-and-how-to-mi/317933#317933

Comment: ok, using the answer proposed [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317933/75098) solves the problem so this question can be marked as a duplicate, thanks !